# To check whether the string value has numeric value or not in C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I am having an string like this

string str = "dfdsfdsf8fdfdfd9dfdfd4"

I need to check whether the string contains number by looping through the array.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What about a regular expression:

```
bool val = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(str, @"\d");
```

Comment: And also have a look at John M Gant answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/how-to-identify-if-string-contain-a-number

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for an integer value you could use **[int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)**:

```
int result;
if (int.TryParse("123", out result))
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Valid integer: " + result);
}
else
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Not a valid integer");
}
```

For checking a decimal number, replace int.TryParse with [**Decimal.TryParse**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx). Check out this blog post and comments ["Why you should use TryParse() in C#"](http://fatagnus.com/why-you-should-use-tryparse-in-c/) for details.

If you need decimal numbers, you could alternatively use this regular expression:

```
return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(
   TextValue, @"^-?\d+([\.]{1}\d*)?$");
```

And finally another alternative (if you are not religiously *against VB.NET*), you could use the method in the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric("abc");
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're going to loop through the string, DON'T use int.TryParse... that's way too heavy. Instead, use char.IsNumber();

example:

```
foreach (char c in myString)
    if (char.IsNumber(c))
        return true;
```

Comment: Instead of using loop, use of regular expression is a good option.

Answer (score 4):

```
str.ToCharArray().Any(x => char.IsNumber(x));
```

Comment: Thanks to [`String.IEnumerable(Of Char).GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc672334.aspx), you actually don't even need the `.ToCharArray()` as the string is automatically cast as an enumerable of type char.

Answer (score 1):

Combining parts of Kamals answer and Tristars answers give...

```
str.Any(char.IsNumber)
```

which I think is the most succinct and readable way, instead of a regex

Answer (score 0):

If you're a linq junkie like me, you'd do it this way

```
string s = "abc1def2ghi";
bool HasNumber = (from a in s.ToCharArray() where a >= '0' && a <= '9' select a).Count() > 0;
```

Comment: Good God, that's hideous.  If I find that in a code review I'd (a) excise it; (b) excise you.

Comment: The code isn't bad - except you should use "Any()" instead of "Count() > 0" - that way you short circuit and don't need to evaluate the rest of the list since you know you've hit 'true' already.

Answer (score 0):

in C# 2.0, try this:

```
        string str = "dfdsfdsf8fdfdfd9dfdfd4";

        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            int result;
            if (int.TryParse(str[i].ToString(), out result))
            {
                //element is a number            
            }
            else
            {
                // not a number
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.ToCharArray().Any(char.IsNumber)
```

Comment: `Any()` takes a predicate, so this will not compile.  Also, this exact answer was [already provided by Kamal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11145727/1366033)

Comment: Actually that method group is a valid predicate, so it does compile, and this answer is not quite the same as Kamals