# IsNumeric check in linq

Tags: c#, linq

The following linq

```
var subjectMarks = (from DataRow row in objDatatable.Rows
                    select Convert.ToDecimal(row["EXM_MARKS"])).Sum();
```

throws an exception since some `row["EXM_MARKS"]` has non numeric values like `AB` etc.
How can I get the sum of only numeric ones out of them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `where` clause that filters out the records that cannot be parsed as decimals. Try:

```
decimal dummy;

var subjectMarks = (from DataRow row in objDatatable.Rows
                     where decimal.TryParse(row["EXM_MARKS"], out dummy)
                     select Convert.ToDecimal(row["EXM_MARKS"])).Sum();
```

Comment: I knw that , I am asking is ther any direct function to handle that ?

Comment: You can select the dummy value without additional Convert.ToDecimal call

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy: No, you can't. This would select the value of the last row for all rows.

Comment: if so, how you can explain this: string value = "1 a 2 b 3 c";
int dummy = 0;
var digits = (from digit in value.Split(' ')
                where int.TryParse(digit, out dummy)
                select dummy).ToList();
digits.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy: Yes, you are right. The deferred execution got me.

Answer (score 5):

You could create an extension method `SafeConvertToDecimal` and use this in your LINQ query:

```
var subjectMarks = (from DataRow row in objDatatable.Rows
                    select row["EXM_MARKS"].SafeConvertToDecimal()).Sum();
```

This extension method would look like this:

```
public static decimal SafeConvertToDecimal(this object obj)
{
    decimal result;
    if(!decimal.TryParse(obj.ToString(), out result))
        result = 0;

    return result;
}
```

This approach has the advantage that it looks clean and you aren't converting each object twice as do all other answers.

Answer (score 3):

For linq to sql queries you can use built-in `SqlFunctions.IsNumeric`

Source: [SqlFunctions.IsNumeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.isnumeric?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
Decimal Z;

var subjectMarks = (from DataRow row in objDatatable.Rows
                     where Decimal.TryParse (row["EXM_MARKS"], out Z)
                     select Convert.ToDecimal(row["EXM_MARKS"])).Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make some extensions utility class like this for elegant solution:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsValidDecimal(this string s)
    {
        decimal result;
        return Decimal.TryParse(s, out result);
    }
}
```

and use it in this way:

```
var subjectMarks = (from DataRow row in objDatatable.Rows
                     where row["EXM_MARKS"].IsValidDecimal()
                     select Convert.ToDecimal(row["EXM_MARKS"])).Sum();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For LINQ to SQL queries with  Entity Framework Core, [`ISNUMERIC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function is part of EF Core 6.0 under [EF.Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.isnumeric?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions-isnumeric(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbfunctions-system-string))

Before version 6.0, you can create a user-defined function mapping !

[`User-defined function mapping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) : Apart from mappings provided by EF Core providers, users can also define custom mapping. A user-defined mapping extends the query translation according to the user needs. This functionality is useful when there are user-defined functions in the database, which the user wants to invoke from their LINQ query for example.

```
await using var ctx = new BlogContext();
await ctx.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
await ctx.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

_ = await ctx.Blogs.Where(b => ctx.IsNumeric(b.Name)).ToListAsync();

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    static ILoggerFactory ContextLoggerFactory
        => LoggerFactory.Create(b => b.AddConsole().AddFilter("", LogLevel.Information));

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost;Database=test;User=SA;Password=Abcd5678;Connect Timeout=60;ConnectRetryCount=0")
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
            .UseLoggerFactory(ContextLoggerFactory);

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(IsNumericMethodInfo)
            .HasName("ISNUMERIC")
            .IsBuiltIn();
    }

    private static readonly MethodInfo IsNumericMethodInfo = typeof(BlogContext)
        .GetRuntimeMethod(nameof(IsNumeric), new[] { typeof(string) });

    public bool IsNumeric(string s) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}

public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid the phrase "LINQ to SQL" in an Entity Framework context. It's quite a different thing.

Comment: It's worth noting that the built-in `ISNUMERIC` will return true for some non-numeric characters, e.g., "+20", "-30", "$2.00". But for expressions like "20+" it will return false, so character positioning matters. Bottom line: If you're looking strictly to exclude all non-numeric characters, you'll need to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
var subjectMarks = objDatatable.Rows.Where(row => row["EXM_MARKS"].ToString().All(char.isDigit))
```

part of solution is getted in: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524957/how-to-check-if-my-string-only-numeric)

Comment: result will be an array with all items numeric