# Check string is numeric by using try parse in c#

Tags: c#

I have value as belowbelow

```
string value = "10053409434400003333336533210923";
```

When I try to parse below it `isNumeric` displays always false result because of long (i think)

```
long n;
bool isNumeric = long.TryParse(value , out n);
if (!isNumeric) // Always false
{

}
```

Where I miss in code how can I check string (**even 50 characters**) value is numeric or not ?

Thanks

Comment: Your code and your question shows/tells different things. Your code try to parse your `string` to `long` which returns `false` because your value is too big for `long` type. Your question says; _how can I check string value is numeric_ which I guess you try to check every character is numeric or not which is _already_ [have a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524957/how-to-check-if-my-string-only-numeric). Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: You also didn't say whether you want to allow a negative value. The LINQ and regex methods in the answers will fail to recognize that.

Comment: Parsing does even more job than simply going through string character by character. Your solution to the problem is similar to one when you convert `int x` to `string` and test its `Lengh` to see if `x > 9 && x < 100`. Correct approach is given by @AlexD answer.

Comment: @SonerGönül yine sallamaya basladın amk

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to check if all characters are digits, without making sure that the number can be represented by an integral type, try Linq:

```
bool digitsOnly = s.All(c => char.IsDigit(c));
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be able to use the parsed number, you will need a type large enough to represent it.  A .NET `long` can support –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807  so I suggest using [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (add a reference to `System.Numerics`)

```
BigInteger number1;
bool succeeded1 = BigInteger.TryParse("10053409434400003333336533210923", out number1);
```

[BigInteger.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268301(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You will need a reference to System.Numerics for this to work.

Comment: yes you are right that's my fault but your code is ok thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You can try this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/894567/1793453

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d+$")
```

Answer (score 2):

The long type is 64 bit and can only hold values from –9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807.

You could use a Regex instead:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d+$");
```