# regex is very slow， how to check if a string is only with word chars fast?

Tags: java, regex

I have a function to check if a string(most of the string is only with one CJK char) is only with word chars, and it will be invoked many many times, so the cost is unacceptable, but I don't know how to optimize it, any suggestions?

```
/*\w is equivalent to the character class [\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}].
 For more details see Unicode TR-18, and bear in mind that the set of characters
 in each class can vary between Unicode releases.*/
private static final Pattern sOnlyWordChars = Pattern.compile("\\w+");

private boolean isOnlyWordChars(String s) {
    return sOnlyWordChars.matcher(s).matches();
}
```

when s is "3g", or "go_url", or "hao123", isOnlyWordChars(s) should return true.

Comment: Do you consider the empty string valid? (i.e w* rather than w+)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to check if string contains only digits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461080/fastest-way-to-check-if-string-contains-only-digits)

Comment: @SK9 c# and java are different languages :P

Comment: @nachokk The question is very likely to elicit the same pseudocode.

Comment: @SK9 it won't. Digits form a single range. Word characters don't. Especially not in Unicode.

Comment: yes, do you have a better solution?

Answer (score 4):

```
private boolean isOnlyWordChars(String s) {
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();    
    for (char c : chars) {
        if(!Character.isLetter(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }    
    return true;
}
```

A better implementation

```
public static boolean isAlpha(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return false;
    }
    int sz = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)) == false) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or if you are using Apache Commons, [StringUtils.isAlpha()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isAlpha%28java.lang.String%29). the second implemenation of the answer is actually from the source code if isAlpha.

**UPDATE**

HI Sorry for the late reply. I wasn't pretty sure about the speed although I read in several places that loop is faster than regex. To be sure I run the following codes in [ideoone](http://ideone.com/) and here is the result

for 5000000 iteration

**with your codes:**    4.99 seconds   (runtime error after that so for big data it is not working)

**with my first code**    2.71 seconds

**with my second code**    2.52 seconds

for 500000 iteration

**with your codes:**    1.07 seconds

**with my first code**    0.36 seconds

**with my second code**    0.33 seconds

[Here](http://ideone.com/FEhB0G#) is the sample code I used.

N.B. There might be small mistakes. You can play with it to test in different scenario.
according to the comment of Jan, I think those are minor things like using private or public. yest condition checking is a nice point.

Comment: multiple return and == false is better implementation?

Comment: @nachokk depends on what your common case is; there's a good chance the first `if` won't even get compiled.

Comment: I updated my questions, "\w is equivalent to the character class [\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}]." e.g. when the string is "3g", or "go_url", or "hao123", isOnlyWordChars(s) should return true.

Comment: Why is the first one `private` and the second one `public static`?

Comment: Also, Nacokk's point was that you should use `!condition` instead of `condition == false`

Comment: @StinePike, this implementation doesn't solve my problem, do you have a better solution?

Comment: @iclinux .. are you facing problem in using isalpha method?

Comment: @StinePike, yes, when str is "3_g", or "go_url", or "hao_123", isOnlyWordChars(str) should all return true, but yours won't...because Character.isLetter() don't equal "\w"(which is equivalent to the character class [\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}].)

Comment: @StinePike yes, is there a way without regx to test if a char is or isnot a "\w"?

Comment: Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)) in place of this condition you can create your own condition then .. including what you want and excluding what you dont want.. so crate your own isLetter method

Comment: the problem is that, I don't know how to write my own isLetter(char), because the char maybe CJK or in other languages...

Answer (score 1):

The only thing i see is to change your pattern to:

```
^\\w++$
```

*but i am not a java expert*

explanations:

I have added anchors (ie `^` `$`) that increases the performances of the pattern (the regex engine fails at the first non word character until it encounters the end). I have added a possessive quantifier (ie `++`), then the regex engine doesn't matter of backtrack positions and is more fast.

more informations [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html%E2%80%8E).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the chief problem is your pattern.

I was working through an iterative solution, when I noticed that it failed on one of my test strings `Supercalifragilisticexpalidociou5`.  This reason for this:  `\w+` only cares if there is one or more word characters.  **It doesn't care if you're not looking at a word character** beyond what it's already matched.

To rectify this, use a lookaround:

```
(?!\W+)(\w+)
```

The `\W+` condition will lock the regex if one or more characters are found to be a non-word character (such as &*()!@!#$).

Comment: That look-ahead will never filter anything. A sequence of non-word-chars never begins where a sequence of word-chars does. Perhaps you wanted the lookahead to be `(?!\w*\W+)` and also to add string anchors?

Comment: The explanation is correct, but the rectification is insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this using regexes, then the most efficient way do it is to change the logic to a negation; i.e. "every character is a letter" becomes "no character is a non-letter".

```
private static final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\W");

private boolean isOnlyWordChars(String s) {
    return !pat.matcher(s).find();
}
```

This will test each character at most once ... with no backtracking.

Comment: thanks, but It doesn't works in my case, because in my case, nearly all the "s" is only with one cjk char... old method costs [61032]ns, yours costs [58115]ns in average.

Comment: is there's a way to check one char is "\w" without regx? because most of the string is with length 1.

Comment: Yea, sure there is.  Use a loop like StinePike's answer.

Comment: no, I can't, because Character.isLetter() don't equal "\w"(which is equivalent to the character class [\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}].)