# Is there a isNumeric function to determine if a string contains numbers?

Tags: c#

I need to check if a string contains only numbers(integers and decimal) with a space in between them. 
Eg: 1 2 4.5 72 (this is acceptable);
1 7..5 3.2.1 (this is unacceptable)

Comment: Remove spaces from the string and try to parse the number to double. There is nothing in built available in C#

Comment: Use String.replace(" ",""); for remove spaces after use try-catch for convert.toDouble

Comment: Does this want to check the individual strings between whitespace or the whole string as a whole? This question as it stands is too broad.

Comment: Why request closing because of off-topic and unclear and too-board? I don't understand. I think it is a good question and I had joy in formulating an answer. This may be usefull. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461080/fastest-way-to-check-if-string-contains-only-digits

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Double.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) to verify if a string is a valid number, assuming integers and floats/doubles in this case. You will have to split the strings by whitespace beforehand using [`String.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) to check each number individually. You can also utilize [`Enumerable.All<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,Boolean>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.8) from LINQ to check if all the strings satisfy a condition.

```
List<string> strings = new List<string> { "1 2 4.5 72", "1 7..5   3.2.1" };

foreach (string item in strings)
{
    if (item.Split (new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).All (str => double.TryParse (str, out _)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine ($"{item} has only valid numbers.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine ($"{item} does have invalid numbers.");
    }
}
// 1 2 4.5 72 has only valid numbers.
// 1 7..5   3.2.1 does have invalid numbers.
```

Comment: I don't think this was what the OP was trying to ask, I understand that he wants to know if the whole string is a number or a double. so I suggest `string.replace` spaces first before passing

Comment: @Bosco This seems a little ambiguous. The OP states that he wants to *"contains only numbers(integers and decimal) with a space in between them*", which means that the string could contain more than one number. Off course one could also interpret it your way as well. He/she needs to clarify this.One of the other answers has also interpreted it my way so its definitely an enquiry to ask.

Comment: This is the correct answer. However it will get issues if you have 2 spaces next to each other, because empty strings will fail the TryParse and return false. I also corrected the resulting statements. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @Battle Thanks, some very good points. I accepted your edits and suggestions because it improves the answer.

Comment: Ah sorry, I made a little mistake: The first string example should have multiple spaces (and still be valid), the second one doesn't need to.

Answer (score -1):

you can use split space first then check every split element numberic yes or not by  `decimal.TryParse + LINQ Any`.

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(  Check("1 2 4.5 72") ); //true
    Console.WriteLine(  Check("1 7..5 3.2.1")   ); //false
}

bool Check(string text)
{
    return text.Split(' ').Any(_ => decimal.TryParse(_, out var num) == false) == false;
}
```

Comment: this will fail if there are two spaces.