# Error in this program of c# validate pin code?

Tags: c#

Here is de ad of the excercise:

> ATM machines allow **4** or **6** *digit* PIN codes and PIN codes cannot contain anything but *exactly* **4** digits or *exactly* **6** digits.
>
> If the function is passed a valid PIN string, return true, else return false.
>
> eg:
>
> `ValidatePin("1234") => true`
>
> `ValidatePin("12345") => false`
>
> `ValidatePin("a234") => false`

And here is the code with the error:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Kata
{
    public static bool ValidatePin(string pin)
    {
        int pinn; //int called pinn declared
        int cont=0; // the same that the count
        int i;  //and the variable i for identify the for
        for(i=0;i<9999;i++)
        {
            cont +=1;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the PIN:"); //tell the user to type the PIN number
        Console.ReadLine(pinn); //read the num pinn
        if(pinn>cont) //if
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong output for",pinn);
        }

        return true || false;
}
```

Error:

> Time: 1889ms Exit Code: 1
>      Test Results:
>       Log
>      src/Solution.cs(16,13): error CS1501: No overload for method 'ReadLine' takes 1 arguments
>      src/Solution.cs(16,22): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'pinn'

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` doesn't need any argument, please read this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to check if string contains only digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461080/fastest-way-to-check-if-string-contains-only-digits)

Comment: `Console.Readline` is a function that returns a value, check [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Console_ReadLine). You have other errors also, like the wrong `Console.WriteLine`, that weird `for` loop and that `return true || false`.

Comment: `bool valid = pin != null && pin.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9') && (pin.Length == 4 || pin.Length == 6);`

Answer (score 0):

As error says, In C# there is no overloaded [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netcore-3.1) method which accept one argument, ReadLine method in Console class reads input from user and stores it in string variable.

As your `pinn` variable is of type `int`, you need to convert input from `Console.ReadLine()` to `int` like,

```
pinn = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Now you assigned some value to `pinn` variable, so you will not face the second error.

---

There is lot of improvement that you can do in your program, your goal is to check that length of pin is 4 or 6. Return `true` if length is 4 or 6 otherwise `false`,

```
public class Kata
{
    public static bool ValidatePin(string pin)
    {

       //below condition will return true if length is 4 or 6, otherwise false
       var condition = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pin)    //Null check for pin
                          && (pin.Length == 4 || pin.Length == 6)  //Length should be 4 or 6
                          && pin.All(char.IsDigit); // Check for all digits

       return condition;
    }
}
```

[.NET FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lUZXMG)

Comment: Counter example: `pin = "-123"` expected `false`, actual `true`; another counter example: `pin = " 123"` (please, note leading space)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thanks for these corner cases. I fixed it using `char.IsDigit` property

Comment: An academic counter example (`pin = "۱۲3۴"` expected `false`, actual `true`) with *Persian* digits still exits, but I doubt if it or alike will appear in real life

Answer (score 0):

In your exercise you are asked to only allow 4 or 6 **digits**. There are many ways to check this. The easiest is with a regular expression, in your program you are already using its reference.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static bool ValidatePin(string pin)
    {
        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^\d{4}(?:\d{2})?$");
        return rgx.IsMatch(pin);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Insert pin:"); 
        string pin = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("The restult is {0}", ValidatePin(pin));
    }
}
```

Comment: More accurate implementation is `new Regex(@"^\d{4}(?:\d{2})?$", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);` otherwise `pin = "۱۲۳۴"` (note *Persian* digits) will match

Answer (score 0):

Why not a simple *direct check*? `pin` is valid if and only if

1. `pin` is not `null`
2. `pin.Length` is either `4` or `6`
3. `All` characters within `pin` are digits within `'0'..'9'` range

**Code:**

```
using System.Linq;

...

public static bool ValidatePin(string pin) =>
   pin != null && 
  (pin.Length == 4 || pin.Length == 6) &&         
   pin.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9');
```