# Pin with regex from codewars Regex validate PIN code

Tags: javascript, regex

"Hello world" i am trying to solve a problem from codewars and i am really struggling with regex. First of all i want to say sorry if my question is not properly written or maybe (dumm question).So to the point

> the pin codes cannot contain anything but exactly 4 digits or exactly 6 digit and not symbols like (-)

```
  if ((pin.match(/^[0-9]+$/) != null && pin.length === 4) || pin.length === 6)
    return true;
  else return false;
} 
console.log(validatePIN("-12345"));// this should be false.It is true because it contains the "-" and length===6
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61767778/3832970) is the regex.

Comment: Your `()` are in the wrong place. It should be: `if (pin.match(/^[0-9]+$/) != null && (pin.length === 4 || pin.length === 6))`.

Comment: yeah it worked!!thanks i think i tried so hard to fix the regex and i didn’t  notice the () in my code thanks a lot