# how to make a text box only to accept numbers in c# for windows web store application using blank template

Tags: c#, windows, textbox, webstore

I  am creating a windows store app  in visual studio 12 , I am using c# language ,i have a text box ,but how to make it to accept only numbers ,if user tries to entry any other value than the number it should show an error message

Comment: Please include some more details regarding your problem and what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please do some research before asking questions. This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/how-to-identify-if-a-string-is-a-number

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if IsNumeric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809340/how-to-check-if-isnumeric)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `try` and `catch` like in following example:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int num;

        try
        {
            num = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);  //here's your value
            label1.Text = num.ToString();
        }

        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            label2.Text = exc.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, as you're writing a Windows Store App and will most likely be dealing with a virtual keyboard, you can make sure that you get a suitable keyboad view by setting the `InputScope` of the `TextBox` correctly ([MSDN link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh702632))

```
<TextBox InputScope="Number" .../>
```

There are a bunch of useful `InputScope` values [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.inputscopenamevalue).

Note that you will *still* need to do validation as described in the other answers, because you have to cater for the user overriding the displayed keyboard type or having an attached physical keyboard. I would do it with a `KeyDown` event handler, like so

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown_Number(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((uint)e.Key >= (uint)Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number0 
        && (uint)e.Key <= (uint)Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number9)
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    else e.Handled = true;       
}
```

Comment: Key Combinations like Shift+1 or Shift+any numeric key it allows, which prints !@# chars.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **try** and **catch**

or you can go for a little bit more code to determine whether input is number (int or double) or not by doing this

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool TFmBatteryConfiguration::IsValidInt(char* x)
{
    bool Checked = true;

    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        //valid digit?
        if (isdigit(x[i]))
        {
            //to the next character
            i++;
            Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //to the next character
            i++;
            Checked = false;
            break;
        }
    } while (x[i] != '\0');

    return Checked;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool TFmBatteryConfiguration::IsValidDouble(char* x)
{
    bool Checked = true;

    int i = 0;

    do
    {
        //valid digit?
        if (isdigit(x[i]))
        {
            //to the next character 
            i++;
            Checked = true;
        }
        else if (x[i] == '.')
        {
            //First character
            if (x[0] == '.')
            {
                Checked = false;
                break;    
            }
            else if (x[i] == '.' && x[i+1] == '\0')
            {
                Checked = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //to the next character
                i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
            Checked = false;
            break;
        }
    } while (x[i] != '\0');

    return Checked;
}
```

The code above is taken straight from one of my project in C++. but the idea is the same. 
C# is provided with **char.isDigit()**