# How to get the real type in a string?

Tags: c#, string, types

How can I get the real type that is in the string in c#? 
For example, the method gets a string- `"123"` and it need to find it's real type- `int`, and convert this `string` to an `int` variable. Is there a simple way to do it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the real type of "0"? It could be int, short, long, float, double or decimal...

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: Well, you'd have to define the PRIORITY list for this, e.g. `"123"` can be both `int` and `long` (not to mention a few others :)). So essentially your app needs a convention, and then you'd write one big if else a la `int i; if (int.TryParse("123", out i)){return i;} bool b; if (bool.TryParse("123", out b) {return b;}` etc

Comment: in simple words, string is always a string even if it has numeric values. check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809340/how-to-check-if-isnumeric

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. In your case, there are different types, that could be possible: `int`, `short`, `long`...

You should decide to what type you want to parse your string.