# How to check if string is a number in C#

Tags: c#, .net

In WinForm I need to check if the value in the TextBox is a number or not.

In PHP there is `is_numeric` function. Is something similar available in .NET?

Comment: @JustinNiessner - The OP is looking for a function similar to PHP's [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php). The linked answer does not provide some of the more advanced capabilities requested.

Comment: I'm satisfied with the link. No need to reopen. I just hope I'll be able to delete the question in two days:)

Comment: I just felt annoyed by the fact that all the C# ninjas jumped into Int32.TryParse without checking what PHP is_numeric function covers..

Comment: As this question is closed, I've added my answer to the linked question. It actually answers the stated question: replicating `is_numeric`. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/16303109/211627 (Even if the OP is satisfied with the linked question/answer, replicating `is_numeric` is still an interesting challenge)

Comment: Thanks Cyborg37. I totally forgot about possible signs, digits in the numbers. upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use TryParse to check

```
string str = "123";
int i;

if (int.TryParse(str, out i))
{
    // it's an int
}
```

you should be able to do similar with other types, such as `double`

Comment: If you check the documentation for PHP's `is_numeric`, you'll find that `"0x4a"`, `"7.9"` and `"+1.2e3"` should also return `true`.

Answer (score 2):

[`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)

```
int val;
bool parsed = Int32.TryParse(input_str, out val);
```

Gives you both if it's a valid int and the result of parsing it as int as well (in val)

Answer (score 1):

```
int number;
string str="!23";
if(int.TryParse(str, out number))
{
    //do something
}
```

if you are 100% sure its an int you can use:

```
int.Parse(str);
```

or

```
Convert.ToInt32(str);
```

it will cast an execption if its not an int

Answer (score 0):

[double.tryparse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) will allow you to check the string.