# Syntax for conformation of possible to convert

Tags: c#

I want to gain a true or false answer if this variable is enable to be converted from string into a int value.

Is there a build-in syntax for it in C#?

Comment: This question is unclear - and there is no "special syntax" for it. Provide input and expected output.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/how-to-identify-if-a-string-is-a-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `int.TryParse`

```
string numberString = "123";
int number;
bool isConvertible = int.TryParse(numberString, out number);
```