# How to validate a string so that it's not empty and contains numeric values?

Tags: c#, validation, console

As I am making a console application I can't seem to get the `.Length` to check whether it's empty for an `if` statement to work, says that it's "read only".

I can't simply define the value as `int` due to using console to retrieve the data.

```
Console.Write("Enter your Phone Number:  ");
phone_number = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Managed to get the length of string as a temp val, still unsure about the only numeric!

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/how-to-identify-if-a-string-is-a-number) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int.TryParse()`. It returns true if the string is a valid `int`. If the string is empty or not numeric it will return false. You didn't mention it in your question so I am assuming you aren't entering in decimal numbers (ie. 34.12).

```
int phoneNumber;

if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out phoneNumber))
{
     // phone number was an int
}
else
{
     // not an int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's very simple.

first you check if the string is null or empty using this Method:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(string value)
```

if the method returned **true** it means that you should not continue(the string is null or empty).

then you want to check that if the string can be converted to int(number).so you can use:

```
public static bool TryParse(
string s,
out int result)
```

If you want to know more about *int.TryParse* method,you can refer to http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-tryparse for a simple tutorial.

Happy codding. If you have anymore answers,I'm ready here :D

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly your question, you should use only the digits of your input as a phone number. The format may vary but still be valid:

```
(+001)555-123456

555 123456

123456

555 12 34 56
```

All valid answers to the question. Don't make people type their number in ways they never do it. Just accept their input and take what you need:

```
Console.Write("Enter your Phone Number:  ");
var input = Console.ReadLine();

string phoneNumber = new string(input.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Comment: +1 for user-friendly input

Comment: Is this a valid phone number `०१२७८` ?

Comment: @Selman22 personally, I'd say no, because I'd have a hard time dialing it. But if it's actually digits and I just don't know how to translate it to arabic numbers, then maybe yes.

Comment: I just took some random numbers from [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm) my point is `char.IsDigit` returns true for all those digits. and I think op most likely wants only latin digits (0-9)