# How to validate datagridview input by the value type of column in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datagridview

I am trying to validate datagridview input by the value type of respective column, this is my code:

```
 private void dgvLoadTable_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
 {
   foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvLoadTable.Rows)
   {
    foreach (DataGridViewCell dc in dr.Cells)
    {
      if (dc.GetType() == typeof(Int32) || dc.GetType() == typeof(Double))//if(dc.ColumnIndex==0)
      {
       DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = dgvLoadTable[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewTextBoxCell;
       if (cell != null)
       {
        char[] chars = e.FormattedValue.ToString().ToCharArray();
        foreach (char c in chars)
        {
         if (char.IsDigit(c) == false)
         {
          MessageBox.Show("You have to enter digits only");
          e.Cancel = true;
          break;
         }} }
          }
         }
        }
    }
```

But this is not working, what should be the type for a number column? FYI, this is an winForm application and different data is loaded in the datagridview on runtime by user choice. So columns are not known previously. The datagridview is bound to an entity model.

Answer (score 1):

First this depends on a datatype in your source collection.
So it may be decimal or some other numeric values.
Best if you put conditional a breakpoint in this method for certain cell (column).

Also I would avoid iterating thru each row anc column because this method is called for specific cell.

So rather than doing foreach for row / cell you may want to get exact data for cell by using e.RowIndex and e.ColumnIndex to extract cell data object from your data source.

My src looks is a list of objects:

```
class TestData
{
     public Decimal Value { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Initialized like this:

```
List<TestData> src = new List<TestData>();
src.Add(new TestData() { Name = "Test 1", Value = 10 });
src.Add(new TestData() { Name = "Test 2", Value = 20 });
dataGridView1.DataSource = src;
```

And my test can be done here:

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        if ( null != row)
        {
            var cell = row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            if ( null != cell)
            {
                object value = cell.Value;
                if ( null != value )
                {
                    // Do your test here in combination with columnindex etc
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Of course there are many ways of trying / checking type. Depends what exactly you want to test for,

Comment: Can't use column index or name, because which table will be loaded in the datagrid is not known beforehand. I have 10 + tables and they are loaded according to user selection.

Comment: yes but using the above you are validating certain cell not the whole table... Then you can use http://stackoverflow.com/a/894296/4123158 to check whenever value is "numeric"

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell dc in dr.Cells)
            {
                int x;
                double y;
                if (int.TryParse(dc.Value.ToString(),out x) || double.TryParse(dc.Value.ToString(),out y))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You have to enter digits only");
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps you. I recommend you use the tryparse functions to see if the value entered is a number or not. You may use this function for DataGridView_CellValueChanged function as well.

Comment: this is giving me exception- object reference is not set to an instance of an object while running the program.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the last one, here is a new block of code. I've tried it its working.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int x;

        if (this.Visible && !int.TryParse(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(), out x))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have to enter digits only");
            dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = "";
        }
    }
```