# How can we validate a string variable for numeric format?

Tags: asp.net, .net

The if condition is only checking for null or empty, this wouldn't fix the flaw. 
I want to check whether the `Year` string contains a number.

```
string Year = Request.Params[""year""];
if (Year == null || Year.Equals(""""))    
{    
    Year = System.DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();    
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to identify if a string is a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/how-to-identify-if-a-string-is-a-number)

Answer (score 0):

Use TryParse:

```
int x;
if (Year == null || Year.Equals("""") || !int.TryParse(Year, out x)){
     // your code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It will check if a string contains a numeric value
[image: enter image description]