# How to add condition that values are not numbers

Tags: c#

like now, I just add one addition that less than 0, and I want to add one more condition that if the values that user entered are not numbers, still show the same messagebox.

```
        if(waist <= 0 || height <= 0)
        if (waist <= 0) {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number that greater than 60");
        }
        if (height <=0 ) {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enther a number that greater than 120");
                }
```

Comment: It depends on how you parse them to int's.. What is the type of waist and height?

Comment: double. i want to use out number, but dont know how to use

Comment: To parse `double` specifically, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/894325/1715579) to the linked question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
 String input = Console.ReadLine() //Or whatever you are using to catch the user input
int n;
    if(int.TryParse(input, out n)
    {
         //Your logic, use n or something
    }
    else
    {
         //print error that there is no numeric input
    }
```

Comment: but can i use out number?

Comment: what do you mean?, see edit, yes you can use "n" in this example

Comment: And why did you down vote?