# CellValidating for only can input number

Tags: c#, datagridview

I using this code for validation integer input on datagridview.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot Empty!");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else if (...)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Only can input number!");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

and now I have trouble on the code that I put a dots. is there any that can give you an idea ? whether the use regex can be used in these conditions ?

Comment: [check if the string is numeric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/how-do-i-identify-if-a-string-is-a-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use int.Tryparse and call a method to it, something like this, but I haven't checked this code, just a quick example.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot Empty!");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else if (!isNumeric(e.FormattedValue.ToString())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Only can input number!");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

    }
```

Put a method somewhere like this

```
    public static bool IsNumeric(string theNumber)
    {
        if (theNumber == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("theNumber");

        int n;
        bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(theNumber, out n);
        return isNumeric;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried it. but I get an error on ! IsNumeric .

Comment: oh sorry! this my fault , it turns out the advice you gave succeed . thanks bro !

Answer (score 1):

```
int n;
bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out n);
```

put this code before your "if" and then check isNumeric in else if block

Comment: Thank you for your advice , but still error on !isNumeric

Comment: can you provide the error message? maybe e.FormattedValue is null

Comment: '!isNumeric' is a 'variable' but is used liked a 'method'

Comment: well of course it's a value, you must use is without parenthesis. it is already calculated

Comment: I tried to re-code provided @prospector and it worked. I did a little mistake . I 'm sorry for wasting your time . thanks for any advice and answer

Comment: these are basically the same solution, glad you managed to fix it anyway :)