# Check if string is numeric in one line of code

Tags: c#, string, int, dotnetnuke, tryparse

I'm working with a DNN form-building module that allows for some server-side code to be run based on a condition. For my particular scenario, I need my block of code to run if the first 4 characters of a certain form text are numeric.

The space to type the condition, though, is only one line and I believe gets injected into an `if` statement somewhere behind the scenes so I don't have the ability to write a mult-line conditional.

If I have a form field called `MyField`, I might create a simple conditional like this:

```
[MyField] == "some value"
```

Then somewhere behind the scenes it gets translated to something like `if("some value" == "some value") {`

I know that `int.TryParse()` can be used to determine whether or not a string is numeric but every implementation I've seen requires two lines of code, the first to declare a variable to contain the converted integer and the second to run the actual function.

**Is there a way to check to see if the first 4 characters of a string are numeric in just one line that can exist inside an `if` statement?**

Comment: Is using an extension method out of the question to use `TryParse`?

Comment: definitely an extension method

Comment: @ScottKaye - I've never used extension methods. Googling around to see how to use them and I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @ScottKaye Since the is being injected into code I doubt that an extension method could be used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I identify if a string is a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/how-do-i-identify-if-a-string-is-a-number)

Comment: @user3185569 - This isn't a duplicate. I need a one-line solution, not a two-line.

Comment: @TheIronCheek There are multiple one-line solutions in the answers provided in that question .

Comment: @TheIronCheek 1-liner from that other Q/A: `bool b1 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric("1"); //true`

Comment: @TheIronCheek `if (str.Take(4).All(c => c.IsDigit()) { ... }`

Answer (score 11):

Wrap it in an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNumeric(this string input)
    {
        int number;
        return int.TryParse(input, out number);
    }
}
```

And use it like

```
if("1234".IsNumeric())
{
    // Do stuff..
}
```

**UPDATE since question changed:**

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool FirstFourAreNumeric(this string input)
    {
        int number;
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || input.Length < 4)
        {
            throw new Exception("Not 4 chars long");
        }

        return int.TryParse(input.Substring(4), out number);
    }
}
```

And use it like

```
if("1234abc".FirstFourAreNumeric())
{
    // Do stuff..
}
```

Comment: Doesn't handle long numeric numbers, nor does it handle comma/period delimiters.

Comment: This answers the question, but using `@this` as a parameter name is a very, very bad choice. Not to mention using it as an extension method parameter. Personally i find using keywords as parameter and variable names as something to be avoided.

Comment: @user3185569 - You might be right regarding the parameter name. I changed it to `input`. Personally I find `@this` very logical in this (pun not intended) particular case just because it shows what your extension is extending. But that's just me.

Comment: @AgentFire - Yes, in that case you might want to use `Int64.TryParse`, but I understood the OP as `int.TryParse` could be used, but not in a single line.

Comment: return int.TryParse(input, out int number); saves 1 line.

Comment: This is great, since I'm only iterating through one character at a time in a string, and I need to check if that character is a number. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**In response to this:**

> Is there a way to check to see if the first 4 characters of a string are numeric in just one line that can exist inside an if statement?
>
> You guys don't have to make it account for anything more complicated than a positive integer.

```
new Regex(@"^\d{4}").IsMatch("3466") // true
new Regex(@"^\d{4}").IsMatch("6")    // false
new Regex(@"^\d{4}").IsMatch("68ab") // false
new Regex(@"^\d{4}").IsMatch("1111abcdefg") // true

// in an if:
if (new Regex(@"^\d{4}").IsMatch("3466"))
{
    // Do something
}
```

---

**Old answer:**

If you can't use `TryParse`, you could probably get away with using LINQ:

```
"12345".All(char.IsDigit); // true
"abcde".All(char.IsDigit); // false
"abc123".All(char.IsDigit); // false
```

If you can, here's an `IsNumeric` extension method, with usage:

```
public static class NumberExtensions
{
    // <= C#6
    public static bool IsNumeric(this string str)
    {
        float f;
        return float.TryParse(str, out f);
    }

    // C# 7+
    public static bool IsNumeric(this string str) => float.TryParse(str, out var _);
}

// ... elsewhere

"123".IsNumeric();     // true
"abc".IsNumeric();     // false, etc
"-1.7e5".IsNumeric();  // true
```

Comment: problem is this doesn't !00% verify it's an `int`

Comment: @Jonesopolis True, it's a workaround for sure.  The extension method approach is better, but if OP is just after a basic "string only contains numbers" method, it should work.

Comment: @AgentFire Neither does `int.TryParse`.  I'll update to use `float.TryParse` for the extension method.  This problem could be solved in a lot of ways (including regex), the "best" solution just depends on what the OP needs.

Comment: You guys don't have to make it account for anything more complicated than a positive integer. I'll update the question to be more specific about this.

Comment: "".All(char.IsDigit); 

returns "TRUE"

Comment: @M.FawadSurosh Personally I would handle that as a different validation case.  For example, **1)** the string should have a complete value (`!string.IsNullOrEmpty`), and **2)** string is numeric (my solution)

Comment: I have already done it that way but I would love it if I could handle all in one condition.

Comment: @M.FawadSurosh In that case, the `IsNumeric` extension method from my answer might work for you.  It simply tries to parse the string as a float, which will handle decimals, negatives, numbers like `1e3`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

How about some easy LinQ?

```
if (str.Take(4).All(char.IsDigit) { ... }
```

Comment: What about negatives and decimals?