# identify if QVariant is String or Int

Tags: c++, string, qt, int

I will do a method that write data on modbus.
I need that QVariant return if is String or Int.

My var.:
**QVariant dataToWrite**

Exist a method that return dataToWrite content is String or Integer?
In c# I did how this solution: [How do I identify if a string is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/how-do-i-identify-if-a-string-is-a-number)

I saw documentation on this link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html
But in qt i didn't find solutions.

Thanks

Comment: If you can cast it to int with `QVariant::toInt()`, than it's an int, otherwise it's a string or anythings else, because you can convert any QVariant to string anyways.

Comment: Try with `int QVariant::toInt(bool *ok = Q_NULLPTR) const`

Comment: example: `bool ok;  int number =your_variant.toInt(&ok); if(ok){ qDebug()<<"is number" }`

Comment: your solutions all work. Thanks. I could think of it before.

Answer (score 16):

To know if a `QVariant` is a `QString` or an integer you have to use `QVariant::type()` or `QVariant::userType()`.

```
bool isInteger(const QVariant &variant)
{
    switch (variant.userType())
    {
        case QMetaType::Int:
        case QMetaType::UInt:
        case QMetaType::LongLong:
        case QMetaType::ULongLong:
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool isString(const QVariant &variant)
{
    return variant.userType() == QMetaType::QString;
}
```

If you use other methods to get the type of the variant, you will get wrong answers.

For instance:

```
// This function does not work!
bool isInteger(const QVariant &variant)
{
    bool ok = false;
    variant.toInt(&ok);
    return ok;
}

QString aString = "42";
QVariant var = aString;
isInteger(var); // Returns true, but var.type() returns QMetaType::QString !!!
```

Now if you want to know if a `QVariant` can be converted to an integer, you have the beginning of an answer in Qt [Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#toInt):

> Returns the variant as an int if the variant has userType()
> QMetaType::Int, QMetaType::Bool, QMetaType::QByteArray,
> QMetaType::QChar, QMetaType::Double, QMetaType::LongLong,
> QMetaType::QString, QMetaType::UInt, or QMetaType::ULongLong;
> otherwise returns 0.

Which means that there are many non integer variants that can be converted to an integer. The safest way to do it is to use `QVariant::canConvert()` and `QVariant::value()`:

```
QString aString = "42";
QVariant var = aString;
if (var.canConvert<int>())
{
    auto anInteger = var.value<int>();
}
```

Comment: Not sure if "canConvert" is reliable. I.e. try converting "QVariant(QString, "71.62465753424658")" to an int. "canConvert" will return true, and "value<int>()" will return 0.

Comment: @Gediminas `canConvert()` only tells you if `QVariant` knows how to convert between 2 types. It does not tell you if the conversion will go well. In your case `QVariant` knows how to convert a `QString` to an `int`: it will call `String::toInt()`, the issue is that `QString::toInt()` will return `0` because `71.62465753424658` is not an `int`.

Answer (score 4):

`QVariant::canConvert()` is a templated method that returns true or false, whether the variant can be converted to a particular type. From its help:

```
QVariant v = 42;

v.canConvert<int>();              // returns true
v.canConvert<QString>();          // returns true
```

So it not does check if the construction argument was exactly an `int` or a string yet looks sufficient for your purposes.