# I want to know, how to highlight non numeric value by color in DataGridView column in button click C#

Tags: c#

I want to highlight non-numeric value by a color by clicking a button in C#. I have tried below code to get output, however I got no success.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
private void Stnineteen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       

        for (int i = DataGridView1.RowCount - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < DataGridView1.RowCount - 0; j++)
            {
                string grid1 = DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString();

                if (grid1 =="")
               {
                    DataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    //break;

                }
                else if(grid1 == "0")
                {

                    DataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    //break;
                }
                else
                {
                    DataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: What is `j` used for? Also can you explain "*I got no success*"? What did it do vs what you expected? Any error?

Comment: According to given code, i can get output by highlighting a red color for null values (blank cells) and equaled zero values in datagridview column. my question is, how to highlight non numeric values by a color, how to code it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify if a string is a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/identify-if-a-string-is-a-number)

Comment: Can you clarify if you're only wanting to do this in Cells[10] (11 column) or were you intending for the `j` loop to handle all cells in the row? (Which by the way should use ColumnCount).

Comment: Yes, Cells[10] (11 column),  please ignore j, use i to ColumnCount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
double d;
foreach(DataGridViewRow r in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (r.IsNewRow) return;  //we don't want to do anything to the edit row.

if (r.Cells[1].Value == null || r.Cells[10].Value.ToString() == "0")
{
    r.Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
else if(double.TryParse(r.Cells[10].Value.ToString(), out d)) //if it can be parsed to a number
{
    r.Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
else
{
    //Cannot be parsed to a number 
    r.Cells[10].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

Comment: Dear charles, Thank you, it is working. my question is, how to highlight non numeric values by a color, how to code it.

Comment: @RoshanAbrew, Is this what you're asking? I've updated my code to try and parse the value in the cell and if it can successfully be parsed to a number then it colors it green, otherwise, it colors it yellow.

Comment: Dear Charles, ohh, it was succeed,  you are a great....!, you have solved burning problem for me, thank you very much for your support.

Comment: i had spend more time to solve this, but i couldn't, thank you very much once again...!

Comment: @RoshanAbrew Glad it worked, make sure you mark this as the answer so that others can benefit from your question.