How do i do in C# that if the user types not a number it writes invalid input and if its a number it continues?
I Am Making A Mini Game That Is Not Important But Here Is What I Got Rn
That's What It Looks Lik
If (Int.tryparse(userinput2, Out Idk What Out Means))
Like I Said I Tried This Method And I Don't Want To Have A Set Of Numbers I Want It To Detect If Its Any Number Or Not And I Searched The Whole Internet So I Decided To Post It Here

"Idk What Out Means" - then I would suggest you research that. The very first hit for a Google search for "out c#" for me is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out

(I'd also strongly recommend that you don't write everything in title case. I can't speak for anyone else, but personally I find that really hard to read. Additionally, when providing sample code, please format it and make it as "real" as you can - using the appropriate capitalization that would be in the real code.)

The 'int.TryParse(test, out int result)' will put the parsed 'test' into 'result' variable if the conversion is possible (the 'test' is convertible to an integer).
Anyway this post should be helpful enough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/identify-if-a-string-is-a-number
