# If textBox1 Contains Integer

Tags: c#, integer

I just have a simple question... How do I check to see if a textbox or a string contains an Integer?

please no code just maybe a hint or two :D

thanks all :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268120/to-check-whether-the-string-value-has-numeric-value-or-not-in-c

Comment: thanks for link @phoenix, it didn't come up in my search on SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hint 1: have a look on the static methods of int... there are 2 methods

hint 2: try regex

Answer (score 3):

int.TryParse( ....

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expression pattern.

Comment: Strongly agree on this as this is a good way to validate input

Answer (score 2):

Hint: There is a method in Int32 that returns false if passed object is not an integer.

Answer (score 2):

use this regex pattern to validate if the text contains numbers only:

^[0-9]+$

when invalid, means that there is non numeric chars.

Regex regex = new Regex("^[0-9]+$");

regex.IsMatch(textbox1.Text);

Answer (score 1):

regex (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Answer (score 1):

use regular expressions to check if the string contains an integer :

```
    if (Regex.IsMatch(yourString, "\\d"))
    {
        // Do your stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A hint - The value in the textox is a string, try to parse it to int and if exception is raised - it is not an integer

**EDIT:** Actually there is a method which does that - [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

Comment: Another hint - call a function that tries to parse it and check the return value

Answer (score 0):

you can try `int.TryParse` or LINQ. The preferable and probably cleanest solution would be a RegEx, though.